# printing items in an array won't print the items

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 20

struct Item
{
int SKU;
char name[MAX_LENGTH+1];

};

int contains(void)
    {
    int compare;
    return 0;
    }

void displayItemWith(struct Item item[], int count)
    {
    int i;

    char alphabet;
    i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
            //char inventory[ ] = {item->SKU};
            printf("%d", item[i].SKU);
    }



int main(void)
{
int compare;
char count;

    //prints the title
    printf("=== TEST ===\n");
```

// hard-coded inventory 21 items - room for 0 more

```
    struct Item inventory[21] =
    {

    // price  sku  txd qty min  name

            {  .SKU =   275, "Royal Gala Apples"   },
            {  .SKU =   386, "Honeydew Melon"      },
            {  .SKU =   240, "Blueberries"         },
            {  .SKU =   916, "Seedless Grapes"     },
            {  .SKU =   385, "Pomegranate"         },
            {  .SKU =   495, "Banana"              },
            {  .SKU =   316, "Kiwifruit"           },
            {  .SKU =   355, "Chicken Alfredo"     },
            {  .SKU =   846, "Veal Parmigiana"     },
            {  .SKU =   359, "Beefsteak Pie"       },
            {  .SKU =   127, "Curry Chicken"       },
            {  .SKU =   238, "Tide Detergent"      },
            {  .SKU =   324, "Tide Liq. Pods"      },
            {  .SKU =   491, "Tide Powder Det."    },
            {  .SKU =   538, "Lays Chips S&V"      },
            {  .SKU =   649, "Joe Org Chips"       },
            {  .SKU =   731, "Allen's Apple Juice" },
            {  .SKU =   984, "Coke 12 Pack"        },
            {  .SKU =   350, "Nestea 12 Pack"      },
            {  .SKU =   835, "7up 12 Pack"         }
    };


    printf("*** NO MATCHES ***\n");
    printf("=== END ===\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, users, I am trying to print out the list of items 
in output with such format; 
SKU:  275 - Royal Gala Apples
SKU:  386 - Honeydew Melon

but the only thing that would print is the ===TEST===, ***NO MATCHES***, ===END===.

Any reason why?

Comment: Maybe because you don't have any code to print the items?????

Comment: 1) `displayItemWith(inventory, 20);` instead of `printf("*** NO MATCHES ***\n");` 2) `printf("%d", item[i].SKU);
    }` -->  `printf("SKU: %d - %s\n", item[i].SKU, item[i].name);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Because no matter what you do, the "NO MATCHES" will show because you printf it without no conditions. Also, in order to print the list you need to call the method you made which is "displayItemWith(struct Item item[], int count)" and please declare the struct first for a better approach.example:

```
  struct Books {
  char  title[50];
  char  author[50];
  char  subject[100];
  int   book_id;
  };
```